# Pandas series of timestamps casting to string

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm new to pandas and am curious if there is something wrong with my approach to splitting a date column into separate hour, minute, seconds, etc columns.

I have a column in my dataframe (df) that contains only dates ('dates'). I convert this to a series of timestamps using the below line of code:

```
dt = to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', errors='ignore')
```

When I iterate through dt using a for loop I get all of the dates parsed properly and can call out separate properties of the timestamp without an issue. For example:

```
for i in [d.year for d in dt]:
    print(i) # Correctly prints 2017 for all dates

for i in [d for d in dt]:
    print(type(i)) # Prints <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

But when I attempt to add a new column to my dataframe using the below line of code:

```
df['year'] = Series([d.year for d in dt], index=df.index)
```

I get an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Some example date strings are: '09/22/2017 19:23:12.993', '09/01/2017 02:47:11.593'.

Does anyone know why python appears to be interpreting d as a string in the final example but not in the first two?

Comment: can you provide some sample data where this happens?

Comment: If your `dates` column are dates in your df, you can just do `df['year'] = df['dates'].dt.year`. Otherwise, you might first have to do `df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])`.

Comment: for the data you provide, the problem does not happen

Comment: Just added some examples, sorry about that. After implementing @Scratch'N'Purr's method I believe I found what the actual issue was. I had some date time metadata columns that had the same naming scheme as the date columns I was attempting to parse. It looks like pandas was correctly keeping those as strings and throwing the above error. Thanks for your help everyone.